# Load CodeIgniter Instance in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

The problem I had with using Wordpress was wanting to incorporate CodeIgniter functionality into Wordpress theme files. For example, there are  a header and footer that I include in many of my CodeIgniter view files. That same header and footer also needed to be included in the Wordpress theme.

The idea is to load CI instance and use it on Wordpress.
Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried this.

https://github.com/falexandrou/Codeigniter-Wordpress-Integration

The file path to load CI bootstrap is correct already.
Its result was Error

```
Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php
```

the sites step:
1.   Include this in the following template files at the top:

```
 - 404.php - index.php- archive.php- archives.php
 - links.php -page.php - search.php - single.php */

 <?php
  $wp_ci['return'] = true;
 require('codeigniter.php');
```

2. put codeigniter file along the template dir
   This is supposed to load CI instance so it can be used in Wordpress.

   https://github.com/falexandrou/Codeigniter-Wordpress-Integration/blob/master/ci-wp-thedaylightstudio/codeigniter.php

CI index.php

```
 <?php
 $wp_did_header = true;         
 require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/blog/wp-blog-header.php';
 define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
 require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
 ?>
```

UPDATE:

wp-blog-header

```
  if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {
$wp_did_header = true;
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
wp();
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
 }
```

I successfully load the codeigniter view on wordpress but 
all my ci_site_url function returns `website.com/blog/application`
when it should be `website.com/application`
I put this code on one of WP theme `index.php`

```
  define('STDIN', TRUE);
  $_SERVER['argv'] = array();
  ob_start();
  require('../index.php');
  $GLOBALS['wp_ci_output'] = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  $GLOBALS['CI'] = get_instance();
  require_once(APPPATH.'helpers/wordpress_helper.php');
```

Code Reference:

http://thedaylightstudio.com/blog/2010/06/16/codeigniter-and-wordpress-integration

wordpress-helper.php

```
/**
* Print codeigniter view file in wordpress content
*
* @access   public
* @param    string view file name
* @param    array array of variables to be rendered
* @param    boolean true to return, false to return
* @return   mixed
*/

function wp_ci_load_view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE){
 extract($vars);
  $file = APPPATH.'/views/'.$view.'.php';
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  //echo $contents;
  $CI =& get_instance();
  $check_funcs = array('ci_site_url(', '$this->');

  $replace_funcs = array('site_url_wp_safe(', '$CI->');
  $contents = str_replace($check_funcs, $replace_funcs, $contents);
  $contents = eval('?>'.preg_replace("/;*\s*\?>/", "; ?>", 
  str_replace('<?=', '<?php echo ', $contents)).'<?php ');

   if ($return === TRUE){
   return $contents;
   }
 }
```

https://github.com/falexandrou/Codeigniter-Wordpress-Integration/blob/master/ci-wp-thedaylightstudio/wordpress_helper.php

The writer did say an issue:
  **The only issue with this version is that it always renders the same CI page to get the CI object and you can’t manipulate which page it renders.**
Thanks.

MY_url_helper

`function ci_site_url`: to differ CI site_url and WP site url function

```
 if ( ! function_exists('ci_site_url')){
   function ci_site_url($uri = '')
   {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return $CI->config->site_url($uri);
    }
  }
```

Comment: what version of WP are you using?

Comment: @M.Doye Hi . I am using WP 4.1.1

Comment: You might need to swap `require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/blog/wp-blog-header.php';` with `require_once('path/to/wp-load.php'); `

Comment: in other words use `wp-load.php` not `wp-blog-header.php`

Comment: @M.Doye I have changed it but there is no change. I think it doesnot matter which one I use. `wp-blog-header.php` calls `wp-load.php` file also. I have updated the content in my question

Answer (score 0):

look I have added below code in my **helper file** of codeigniter and **add this helper in config/autoload.php file** to autoload it automatically.

```
/**
 * return CI header to home page cms for 
 */
if (!function_exists('ci_header')) {

    function ci_header() {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $header = $CI->load->view('includes/header.php', '', true);

        return $header;
    }

}

/**
 * return CI footer to home page cms for 
 */
if (!function_exists('ci_footer')) {

    function ci_footer() {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $footer = $CI->load->view('includes/footer_homepage.php', '', true);

        return $footer;
    }

}
```

and put below code in wordpress **`wp-content/themes/my_theme/header.php`**

```
<?php
    echo ci_header();
?>
```

and put below code in wordpress **`wp-content/themes/my_theme/footer.php`**

```
<?php
echo ci_footer();
?>
```

you can use any helper function in wordpress theme templete directly as i am calling **`ci_header()`** and **`ci_footer();`**

Go ahead... and summarize me what else you need to do for your project...

Comment: I get "Call to undefined function". I have wordpress installed on folder "blog" outside "application" in codeigniter. What else should I do?

Comment: I Have the same problem. How did you solve your problem ? any luck ?

Comment: Did you make a helper in codeigniter and did you autoload that helped in adding that helper in config/autoload.php ??

Comment: Anyone found the solution? @MIIB??