# Codeigniter view in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, internationalization

I have a website build with Codeigniter and I need to have a blog. It should be a WordPress so what I decided to do is to add "blog" in my `.htaccess` and install a WordPress in `myweb.com/blog`

It works perfect.

Now, I need to change my theme header and footer from the one that I have already in my web.

How can I do it?

I have the view at `views/common/header.php`, but obviously, I can not load it like this in template/header.php

```
<?php $this->load->view('common/header');?>
```

If I'm not wrong, I should add any code at `header.php` in my template folder. So, the question is, what should I change or add on it??

Thanks a lot!

---

**UPDATE**

I think there should be a helper I could load in codeigniter in order to call that functions on Wordpress

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you loading that view on to another view page or from controller if you are loading view into another view could try <?php echo $this->load->view('common/header');?>

Comment: yes, I'm loading it, but I need to load it inside template/header.php

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/29257293/969068

Comment: I tried to do it, but I had a problem with internationalization... I don't know why, it redirects wrong. I update the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You directly cannot call CI view in wordpress file. Inorder to make changes to wordpress header and footer you will need to modify header.php and footer.php file under wordpress theme (wp-content/themes/your_theme_folder).
Also make sure that you do not modify wordpress default theme directly as any changes to default theme would be lost during wordpress updates.
Best practice is to create child theme and then make your changes over there
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes , here the guide to create child theme.